# Positioning an image over an Iframe that is responive to screen size

Tags: html

How could i position a div or img over an iframe but both the image and div acted as one when the screen is resized

```
<div id="container">
<img alt="" src="/images/uploads/Teams/773291/Website%20Images/mockup.png" />

<div ![enter image description here][1]style="overflow: hidden;">
<iframe scrolling="no" src="/dljones/homes-for-sale/AZ/Anthem" frameborder="0"    style="border: 0px none; margin-left: 0px; height: 3850px; margin-top: -12%; width: 100%;">
</iframe>
</div>
</div>
<style>
#container img {
width: 1060px;
height: auto;
display: block;
margin-left: -30px;
}
#container {
position: relative;
z-index: 9999;
margin-bottom: -22%;
}
</style>
```

example pic:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZpZZ.png

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this jsfiddle and see how that is handled.

http://jsfiddle.net/CkCYE/1/

You have a solid start, I made some adjustments to your original code 
You basically need to set your image's width to `width: 100%` and make sure your iframe is set to 100% height and width.